# Plural with ICU MessageFormat syntax for twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi  I do not know how to use the plural with ICU MessageFormat and twig syntax

If I take this sample : https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#pluralization

what is the syntax in twig ?

`{{ 'num_of_apples', {'apples': 23}|trans }}`

Thanks

Comment: {{ 'num_of_apples'|trans({'apples': 23}) }}  see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#trans